# Where can I download the latest version of Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I went to [www.dropbox.com/downloading](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading) to download and install the latest 64-bit Ubuntu .deb file (dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb ) that is provided on the page. I installed it using the command:

```
orschiro@x230:~$ sudo dpkg -i dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb
```

After launching Dropbox and providing my account credentials, I am then presented with the following screen. Where am I supposed to get the latest version of Dropbox from if not on their official website?

[image]

Comment: I use the instructions from here: https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux. `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -` and `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`. I have version 22.4.24. It installs directly in my home folder and updates automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropbox was previously installed on your system and in order to get the latest version you have to open your home folder with a file manager of your choice, make it show hidden files, stop the running instance of Dropbox and delete the contents of the folder `.dropbox-dist`.

The next time you run Dropbox you'll be asked to download the proprietary daemon and will receive the latest version of the program. From then on Dropbox should keep updating on its own.

Comment: FYI, the "daemon" that's installed by the pop-up like in cl-netbox's answer (in `~/.dropbox-dist` *after* the dropbox .deb is finished installing) does not show up in synaptic/apt/dpkg, and completely removing the dropbox still leaves the .dropbox-dist daemon there & running. So this sounds like the answer...

Answer (score 1):

First remove everything related to Dropbox from an earlier installation.
Choose another installation method - just perform it the following way.

Open a terminal and execute this command : `sudo apt install gdebi`
Right-click the downloaded file and select to open the file with `gdebi`.

Once the installation is finished open Dropbox from the dash.
Click on OK to start the download of the proprietary daemon.

[image]

Once it's finished, a new website opens in your browser ->

[image]

Sign in to connect the computer to your Dropbox account.

Comment: Could you please clarify, why is this wrong installation method? I installed hundreds of deb packages via dpkg besides dropbox with no problem.

Comment: @Michal `gdebi` makes sure that all necessary dependencies are getting installed alongside the Dropbox `.deb` file. I have tested the whole procedure a moment ago before writing the answer. :)

Comment: I'd thought dpkg & gdebi were virtually identical ways to get Debian's to install packages (except for the GUI view inside the package, and the old lintian tab bug using 100% cpu). Doesn't dpkg complain if there's missing dependencies?

Comment: @Xen2050 No, `dpkg` and `gdebi` are slightly different ... all I can say is that I always install external `.deb`files, such as TeamViewer with `gdebi` and it always worked perfectly, all dependencies were installed automatically and I never experienced any issue. :)